# Arduino TFT module 240x320 OLED not working

Tags: c++, arduino

Hello I have an Oled that I bought on AliExpress and it's not working even with adafruit. this is a 2 inch TFT module 240x320 ST7789V GMT020-02 and it has 7 pins. Can someone help me please?

i've tried even the ada fruit benchmark but it doesn't work:(